# React Router is not working when page Refreshing on vercel . App created with Vite+react

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, vercel, vite

[image]

#### please Follow the Image I hope You will understand my problem.

I have made a website using react.js + vite. After deploying on vercel everything is ok. but I am going to share a page link that is https://photofolio-react-ref-sourov.vercel.app/create-page. But after sharing, I noticed that the link is not working. but if First I go home page then I go that route by clicking Link I show that this is working. I didn't face this problem with the `create-react-app template. But Now I used the` vite react` template. I faced the same problem on netlify but I found a solution by docs. but now I can't find any solution. Anybody, please share your experience with this problem please fix it. If you have any problem with my explanation please comment on this question.

Comment: I have the same error with Vite + vue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249976/vercel-vite-404-not-found. I also created a ticket on vercel, and awaiting their repsonse ...

Comment: hey @BenjaminFourgeaud Your answer is working for me too... Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like the linked page with the answer here has been deleted - could anybody provide the solution here?

Comment: Update: Found the answer here! https://stackoverflow.com/a/73133366/1058332

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to vercel configuration with page rewrites.
You should look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70258985/13541914